# Why does Saxon need month-in-year function when I already imported EXSLT?

Tags: xslt, saxon

I have imported the EXSLT date package:

```
<xsl:import href="str/str.xsl" />
<xsl:import href="date/date.xsl" />
```

When I do:

```
<xsl:variable name="month" select="date:month-in-year($pDate)" />
```

I get:

```
XPST0017 XPath syntax error at char 0 on line 186 in {date:month-in-year($pDate)}:
Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named
{http://exslt.org/dates-and-times}month-in-year().
There is no Saxon extension function with the local name month-in-year
```

What does "There is no Saxon extension function with the local name month-in-year" mean?
I have already imported the EXSLT date package.

Comment: Which version of Saxon?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Saxon-EE 9.5.1.6

Comment: XSLT 2.0 has its own date and dateTime support and EXSLT extensions are usually written for XSLT 1.0 processors, often using features that are proprietary to a certain XSLT 1.0 processor. So first consider using the date or dateTime data types and functions defined in XSLT and XPath 2.0 and supported out of the box in Saxon 9. If you need to use EXSLT then make sure the implementation is using features that XSLT 2.0 supports. How does the `date.xsl` look?

Comment: Saxon 9.x is an XSLT 2.0 processor and does not support EXSLT. Doesn't need to, since these functions are available in XSLT 2.0 natively.

Comment: @michael.hor257k This is a very old and large XSL codebase. I would like to avoid editing all those files. Is there an easier way of making this work? Can I use EXSLT with Saxon (earlier versions, ...)? I am using Saxon only for the verbose output it produces on errors. The standard XALAN that comes with Java 7 has got not verbose enough error reporting.

Comment: Can you use Saxon 6.5?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes, just downloaded it. The problem I have is I cannot find an example how to use it in Java code.

Comment: I am afraid I can't help you with that, but surely others will. -- The other thing that puzzles me is the import: you should not need to import anything, only declare the EXSLT `xmlns:date` namespace prefix in the stylesheet header.

Comment: The code was as simple as `TransformerFactory factory = new com.icl.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl()`

Comment: @michael.hor257k I got rid of the import and it started working with saxon 6.5.5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57849/discussion-between-wojtek-and-michael-hor257k).

Comment: Let's not. Is the syntax error problem solved now that you're using an XSLT 1.0 processor? If it is, and you are having **other** issues, please either update your question or post a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import EXSLT modules, the functionality is delivered in the form of named templates rather than functions, so you need to call them using xsl:call-template rather than with an XPath function call. If you look at the content of the module you are importing you'll see it contains no functions, only templates.

Most of the functions/templates in the EXSLT date package are superseded by functions in XPath 2.0, so it's not clear why you are still using the EXSLT version.

Saxon 6.5 supported the EXSLT date package (as XPath functions), but they dropped out of the product some time before 9.5 because they simply are no longer needed with XPath 2.0.

There are probably still quite a few people using Saxon 6.5, but it's not something I would recommend. You say you like the diagnostics in Saxon 9, and you are clearly after more features than you can get in XSLT 1.0, so move forward...

Comment: Revisiting that answer, I see there's an error: the EXSLT date functions are still provided in Saxon 9.5 (PE and EE only).

Comment: but not in the Saxon HE? With xslt 1.0 how to proceed? When need EXSLT ?

Comment: @Xelian please ask a new question rather than trying to add a supplementary question in a comment on an answer to a closed question.